# Proof that the Fourier transform of a positive, real, symmetric function is positive, real, symmetric

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be a real function, symmetric around $x=0$. From the properties of the Fourier transform, we know that $\hat{f}(\omega)$ (the spectrum of $f(x)$) is also a real function, symmetric around $\omega = 0$. However, I need to prove that $\hat{f}(\omega)$ is positive for certain functions $f(x)$. In particular, I am dealing with what I would call "well-behaved" (Gaussian-like) probability density functions: I can assume that $f(x)$ has its (positive) maximum at $x=0$ and strictly decreases smoothly to zero for $x \to \pm \infty$. Can it then be shown that, under the above conditions on $f(x)$, the spectrum $\hat{f}(\omega)$ is positive? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Consider for example
$$
f(x)=(1+x^2)e^{-x^2}.
$$
Then $f(x)>0$ and $f(x)=f(-x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Moreover
$$
f'(x)=-2\,x^3e^{-x^2},
$$
so that it is strictly decreasing in $(0,\infty)$ and achieves its maximum at $x=0$. Finally
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0.
$$
But
$$
\hat f(\omega)=-\frac{e^{-\frac{\omega ^2}{4}} \left(\omega ^2-6\right)}{4 \sqrt{2}},
$$
which is negative if $|w|>\sqrt6$ and positive if $|w|<\sqrt6$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Good answer, but the region of negativity is the reverse of what is stated; It's when $|\omega| > \sqrt{6}$. A positive function should have $\hat f(\omega)>0$ in at least a small region around $\omega=0$ because the integral of a positive function is positive.

Comment: @qgp07 Thanks for noticing. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As the answer by Julián Aguirre shows, the result that you are planning
on proving is not true.  What *is* true is that the Fourier transform
of a real-valued even function is a real-valued even function; but one of the functions
being nonnegative does not imply that its transform is also nonnegative.
See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/21189/6633) on stats.SE
for details of what additional conditions you might need to make the result
be true.

More to the point, since you are interested in probability density
functions that are even functions, here is a result
that might help you.

If $X$ is a continuous random variable that can be expressed as $Y-Z$
where $Y$ and $Z$ are independent identically distributed random
variables, then the density of $X$ is related to the densities of
$Y$ and $Z$ as 
$$f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_Y(y)f_Z(y-x)\,\mathrm dy 
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_Y(y)f_Y(y-x)\,\mathrm dy$$
which is the *autocorrelation* function of the common density of
$Y$ and $Z$, and so is a real-valued even nonnegative function. Its
Fourier transform is thus a *power spectral density*, and so is
also a real-valued even nonnegative function as you desire.
Note that it is *not* necessary for $f_Y$ to be an even function
(though of course it is nonnegative).

Thus, it suffices to find random variables that can be decomposed
into the difference of two independent identically distributed
random variables to get instances of real-valued nonnegative
even functions whose Fourier transforms are also
real-valued nonnegative even functions.